# Where to put callback function in react-transition-group

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, react-transition-group

I want to run a process only after transition has ended.

Here the docs say:

> **addEndListener**
>
> Add a custom transition end trigger. Called with the transitioning DOM
>   node and a done callback. Allows for more fine grained transition end
>   logic. Note: Timeouts are still used as a fallback if provided.
>
> ```
> addEndListener={(node, done) => {
>   // use the css transitionend event to mark the finish of a transition
>   node.addEventListener('transitionend', done, false);
> }}
> ```

So I use it like this:

```
<Transition
  addEndListener={(node, done) => {node.addEventListener('transitionend', done, false);}}>
  <MyComponent />
</Transition>
```

The problem is I don't understand where to put my function to be executed after the transition ended.

If this is my function:

```
function abc() {
  // blah
  // blah
  //blah
}
```

Where can I put it? Should I put it in the place of `done`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `addEndListener`, or even `onExited` and `onEntered` callbacks.

With `addEndListener`:

```
function abc() {
  // blah
  // blah
  //blah
}

... // some code

<Transition
  addEndListener={(node, done) => {node.addEventListener('transitionend',(e) => {
    abc(e);
    done(e);
  }, false);}}>
  <MyComponent />
</Transition>
```

With `onEntered` and `onExited`:

```
<Transition
   onEntered={abc} onExited={abc}>
  <MyComponent />
</Transition>
```

An important thing of the second example: check the moment, when you want to get your callback called.